# How to make a string "flash"?

Tags: java, string, swing

I don't mean just appear and disapear. I mean like really quick flashes, millisecond-speed. Any ideas?

Comment: Plenty, what framework are you using? Console, Swing, AWT, SWT, GWT, HTML, some other I can't be bothered to think of?

Comment: 1997 wants its `<blink>` tag back!

Comment: "Any ideas?" - yea, supply your users with a vomit bucket ...

Comment: One way would be to create a thread with a timer in it. The timer could toggle the string visible/invisible.

Comment: Ohhh...could you eleborate please? I'm fairly rusty

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.coderanch.com/t/331766/GUI/java/Icon-flash it should help!

Comment: @MementoMori Setting the visibility of the label will effect the layout.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared stuff up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Flashy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BlinkPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    protected static class BlinkPane extends JLabel {

        private JLabel label;
        private boolean on = true;

        public BlinkPane() {
            label = new JLabel("Hello");
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(label);
            Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    on = !on;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (!on) {
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0f));
            } else {
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(1f));
            }
            super.paint(g2d); 
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

If you have epilepsy, please don't run this!

Comment: For the sake of safety, the *"If you have epilepsy, please don't run this!"* warning should be at the top, **in bold.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson Add in "good taste" as well :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer- thanks a lot for your code. However, it's not recognizing Timer. I'm imported Java.util.Timer, and still nothing.

Comment: @tussya That's because it's using a `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: It is the `javax.swing.Timer` you should use.  (And in an aside to the answerer)  That is one of the reasons why I insist an SSCCE include imports, to make everything explicit.  ;)

Comment: When I import it, it says that it has already been imported in a single type import, (java.util.Timer) but it's not recogizing it

Comment: @AndrewThompson What?  You want me to make their lives easier!? 8O

Comment: *"make their lives easier!?"*  But no, wait.  (narrows eyes)  That's *exactly* what they'd be expecting!   (With apologies to Elliot Ness.)

Answer (score 4):

Millisecond-rate flashing is not practical.  The nominal screen refresh rate of a typical display is typically in the region of 50hz or slower.  That is 1 per 20 milliseconds flash rate ... an order of magnitude slower than "millisecond speed".

And ignoring that "quibble", the chances that you will be able to get a Java app on a stock PC / OS to reliably flash some text at anywhere approaching the screen refresh rate without some serious low-level graphics work ...

---

Doing this *reliably* using the Swing high-level APIs is likely to be difficult.  You most likely need to drill down to the level of painting bits onto a "canvas" and flipping images.

And I don't think your users are likely to appreciate / enjoy the experience ...

And bright flashing lights and screens present **serious** health issues [for some people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy).  So be very, very careful.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'm doing an experiment on flashing speeds correlating learning rates for the Science Fair, and thought this could work...

Comment: @tussya - In that case ... ignore my comments about the user experience, reliability, etc.  Just see if you can make it work.

Comment: @tussya - the other thing to note is that the human eye / brain cannot process visual information at millisecond rates.  (That's why 50hz screen refresh rates work ...)  I think it is worth doing a bit of background reading on this.  (Google / Wikipedia are your friends ...)

Comment: *"I don't think your users are likely to appreciate / enjoy the experience"*  Especially not the [photo-sensitive epileptics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy).  My advice is, don't try this - anywhere for any reason.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - erm yes.  Good point.  I don't imagine that the Science Fair organizers would appreciate having to deal with patrons having epileptic fits in front of his exhibit.  Not to mention the organizers' public liability insurers!

Comment: Yeah, a new topic will probably work better. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

```
<blink><marquee>punch the monkey and win $20</marquee></blink>
```

I think you'll want the scrolling feature as well to increase UX.

EDIT: this will probably only work with netscape navigator and/or IE 5. I forget which ones support which tags.